# Multimodule maven java doc build

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have multimodule maven project like this

```
myproject
  framework1
    f1-presentation
      *.java
    f1-core
      *.java
    f1-tag
      *.java

 framework2
   f2-presentation
      *.java
   f2-core
      *.java
   f2-tag
      *.java
```

I want to create apidocs for all java files. If I run mvn javadoc:aggregate in the project root it creates apidcos in the target directory of project root (target/sites/apidocs). But what I want is to create this apidocs for each 2nd level modules. As for example I want apidocs for all java files of framework1 to be create in framework1/target/sites/apidocs. Same thing goes for framework2. Final result will be like this

```
myproject
 framework1
    target/sites/apidocs (this will contain javadocs for all its submodules classes)
    f1-presentation
      *.java
    f1-core
      *.java
    f1-tag
      *.java

 framework2
    target/sites/apidocs (this will contain javadocs for all its submodules classes)
    f2-presentation
      *.java
    f2-core
      *.java
    f2-tag
      *.java
```

Could you guys tell me how to do that using maven javadoc plugin.

Edit:
pom.xml in framework1 contains

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>aggregate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
```

Comment: what is your config in pom.xml for maven-javadoc-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging, I found that the Maven Javadoc plugin is not so good for a multimodule project. What I wanted to achieve [is not yet supported](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-311).

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this could be to run mvn javadoc:aggregate in each of `framework1` and `framework2` folders separately.

The other would be to configure the poms of `framework1` and `framework2` to `aggregate` as specified in [this example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/aggregate.html) and run `mvn site` from `myproject`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried by adding the javadoc plugin in framework1 and framework2. I set the goal aggregate. But no apidocs is generated in framework1 and framework2